# Java Writing/Appending a File

Tags: java

Hey Stack Overflow people, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how writing and appending files works. Here is what I've been asked to do

• Save (append) the data for the contract to the text-based summary file (contracts.txt).

Each line in the file must hold the details for a single contract with the following information separated by spaces or tabs:

•   Contract Date (today’s date - see technical details for format).

•   Package (1=Small, 2=Medium and 3=Large)

•   Data Bundle (1=Low, 2=Medium, 3=High and 4=Unlimited).

•   Period in Months

•   Allow international call from package minutes  (Y or N)

•   Reference Number.

•   Monthly Charge (in pence).

•   Client Name.

An example of the sort of file I'm looking to write would be [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/VDhgCNru).

So far I have this code

```
    public void appendFile()
    {
        PrintWriter output = null;

        File confidential = new File("contracts.txt");
        try 
        {
            // create new file
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(confidential, true);
            output = new PrintWriter(fw);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) // Problem with file
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Problem creating the file! Program closing");
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Problem creating the file! Program closing");
            System.exit(0);  
        }

        output.print(date);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(minutes);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(data);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(length);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(international);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(ref);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(price);
        output.print(" ");
        output.print(name);

        output.close();

    }// end of main`
```

As you can see, my code is probably wrong and I'm not sure whether or not this method should even be in a seperate class or just stick the code for it in the main class? I appreciate the time it takes to go through my question and I hope someone can help me, as I'm currently about to rip my hair out in frustration of not understanding how to do it.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Looks good to me expect a really small bug, and that bug should be your real question.

Comment: @TangoSheep You should search for the question before asking a new question.

Comment: @AnthonyLaw I tried to search, no questions had answers that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the statement `output.print("\n");` at the end so that each record will be in separate line.

```
output.print(price);
output.print(" ");
output.print(name);
output.print("\n");
```

Comment: @Thanga Sorry, you may cancel the edit :)